# Mock a git repo to test against

Tags: git, unit-testing, testing

Is there an easy way to mock a git server/repo for unit testing purposes? I don't want to test git itself, rather how my code interacts with git.

I'd like to do something like

```
create git@localhost.com:myRepo.git c:/somepath
copy somefile.txt c:/somepath
```

and then when I

```
git clone git@localhost.com:myRepo.git
```

the entire contents of c:/somepath (somefile.txt) is returned, no authentication needed. I want to test how my code handles the clone, so all calls to this git repo should automatically pass authentication.

I looked at git daemon but it runs on real git, so my test code ended up have to do a lot of repo content management (adding, committing, branching etc), which seems unnecessary.

Answer (score 5):

You don't need a server to clone. It will work on a normal directory.

Make a repository.

```
$ git init /path/to/repo
```

Put some stuff in it.

```
$ cd /path/to/repo
$ touch foo bar
$ git add .
$ git ci
[master (root-commit) 3c99023] Some files.
 2 files changed, 0 insertions(+), 0 deletions(-)
 create mode 100644 bar
 create mode 100644 foo
```

Clone it.

```
$ git clone /path/to/repo /path/to/clone
$ cd /path/to/clone
$ ls
.git  bar  foo
```

Note that git won't like it if you push to a non-bare repository, so you might want to make the intermediate step of turning `/path/to/repo` into a bare repository. Simplest thing way to do that is to make a bare clone and use that for everything else to clone from.

```
$ git clone --bare /path/to/repo /path/to/upstream
$ git clone /path/to/upstream /path/to/clone
...use /path/to/clone as normal pushing to /path/to/upstream...
```

You could also just make a bare clone initially and not pre-populate it.

Answer (score 4):

Looks like you might be able to use JGit for this purpose. Here's an example of using it to create an empty repository which can be connected to over http:

https://github.com/centic9/jgit-cookbook/blob/master/httpserver/src/main/java/org/dstadler/jgit/server/Main.java

Answer (score 0):

You could create your own script that exists in a local directory called 'git' and mock out any behavior you want from there.

Comment: I'd need to simulate https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Internals-Transfer-Protocols I guess. Was hoping a mock for this already existed..